# Powershell, Service Bus For Windows Server Programmatically: Command found, module could not be loaded

Tags: c#, powershell, servicebus

From C# code I'm trying to retrieve all the namespaces from powershell... (Later more complex things, like creating namespaces)

```
PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
ps.AddCommand("Import-Module").AddArgument("ServiceBus").Invoke();
var result = ps.AddCommand("Get-SBNamespace").Invoke();
```

Above code gives the following exception:

> The 'Get-SBNamespace' command was found in the module 'ServiceBus',
>   but the module could not be loaded. For more information, run
>   'Import-Module ServiceBus'.

Does anyone know how to solve this error?

**CURRENT STATUS:** after some debugging I've found that no modules are loaded by default in the PowerShell object. Using the code:

```
InitialSessionState iss = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault();
iss.ImportPSModule(new string[]{@"serviceBus"});
PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create(iss);
```

doesn't work to load the service bus module. Also the code:

```
ps.AddCommand("Import-Module").AddParameter("-Name", "serviceBus").Invoke();
```

doesn't work to import the service bus module. Running Visual Studio in administrator mode also doesn't make a difference

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using PowerShell version 3? Is the `Get-SBNamespace` cmdlet working in a PowerShell window? Maybe you need to `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force`?

Comment: Everything is working correctly when executing it from the powershell Window... Currently using Powershell 3.0. It's only giving the exception when it is executed from C# code. Running the code:        ps.AddCommand("Set-ExecutionPolicy").AddArgument("Unrestricted").AddParameter("Force");                                                       Doesn't help

Comment: Where are you running this, local/remote?  What platform (version of Windows, SPs, x86/x64) are you developing on?  What platform is it running on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't say which version of Visual Studio you're using.  If it's VS 2012, when you tried the x64 platform target did you make sure that "Prefer 32-bit" was not checked?  Even if it was not checked try checking it, saving the project configuration, clearing it and saving again - this worked for me on another project.

**UPDATE**

It's been suggested elsewhere that there's a bug in VS2012 that shows "Prefer 32-bit" as greyed-out and unchecked when it's actually active.  I'm running Update 2 and I don't see that.  But it sounds like you might be.  I suggest you edit the .csproj file directly.

Whilst "Platform Target" is set at "Any CPU", in Solution Explorer, right-click on the Project name (or, with go to the PROJECT menu) and select "Unload Project". Project files will close and Solution Explorer will display *project name* (unavailable) > The project file was unloaded:

[image: Unloaded Project]

Right-click on the Project name again and select "Edit *project name*.csproj".  The file is XML and mostly comprises **PropertyGroup** and **ItemGroup** elements.  In a console project, the first PropertyGroup usually contains a Platform element which should read AnyCPU if you followed my instructions above.  The next two PropertyGroups are normally for Debug and Release configurations.  If you've added another configuration, it will have its own PropertyGroup.  In each of these, look for an element which reads:

```
<Prefer32Bit>true</Prefer32Bit>
```

What you should have is an element which reads:

```
<Prefer32Bit>false</Prefer32Bit>
```

Either change it or insert it (in each *configuration* ProjectGroup), save the file and close it.  Back in Solution Explorer, right-click the project and select "Reload Project".  Let me know if that solves it.  You can confirm your PowerShell is now running 64-bit by get the result of

```
[System.IntPtr]::Size
```

e.g.

```
ps.AddScript("[System.IntPtr]::Size");
```

which will be **4** in an **x86** process and **8** in an **x64** process.

Which my project set up like this, I was able to load ServiceBus using:

```
ps.AddCommand("Import-Module").AddArgument("ServiceBus");
```

Hopefully, you will, too.

Comment: This checkbox is disabled in VS2012 and can't enable it... Currently this checkobox is not checked

Comment: OK.  The checkbox is normally disabled if you've got the Platform target set at x64 or x86 and enabled if it's set at Any CPU.  Which is it set to?

Comment: currently it is set set Any CPU and is still disabled. But changing it to x64 or x86 don't enables it...

Comment: What type of project is it?

Comment: I've investigated - there may be a bug in VS causing "Prefer 32-bit" to be greyed-out and un-checked under Any CPU.  I've updated my answer to include what I hope will be a fix; I can't reproduce the bug so I can't be sure.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have ServiceBus installed so I can't verify exactly what you've tried but

```
ps.AddCommand("Import-Module").AddArgument("ActiveDirectory").Invoke();
```

worked for me, so your original syntax looks good.

Just to test for failure, I tried:

```
ps.AddCommand("Import-Module").AddArgument("CheeseDirectory");
ps.Commands.Commands[0].MergeMyResults(PipelineResultTypes.Error, PipelineResultTypes.Output);
var importResult = ps.Invoke();
foreach (PSObject result in importResult)
{
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

and got

> The specified module 'CheeseDirectory' was not loaded because no valid
>   module file was found in any module directory.

Have you tried similar?

Comment: The message that this script produced is: "The current processor architecture is: X86. The module: 'C:\Program Files\Service Bus\1.0\ServiceBus.psd1' requires the following architecture: Amd64." But Amd64 is not by default a target architecture is Visual Studio 2012...

Comment: Amd64 is x64.  AMD created it, Intel created Itanium.

Answer (score 0):

Do you take care of your Assembly target in your C# program (x86 versus X64). The module may exist in one target, not in the other. PowerShell exists in both.

Comment: Looked at it but change the target in Visual Studio of the application doesn't work...

Comment: Did you try running ImportModule ServiceBus in both x86 and x64 PowerShell consoles?

Comment: Both consoles?  Are you sure? That doesn't tally with the error you supplied above, which says it has to be x64.

Comment: I installed ServiceBus on my dev machine (using the Web Platform Installer).  In an x64 console, Import-Module works.  In an x86 console, I get "The current processor architecture is: X86.  The module 'C:\Program Files\Service
Bus\1.0\servicebus\servicebus.psd1' requires the following architecture: Amd64."  The capitalization is different from yours but it's otherwise the same error so I think we can safely conclude that ServiceBus will only run in an x64 process.

Comment: @mrtentje, So I was not so far from the reason of the problem. Now you have to understand why your code load the bad PowerShell version.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you're trying to import some modules and execute the cmdlet or function inside the module, right?

So I think you could try the following code:

```
PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
Assembly ass = Assembly.LoadFile(@"yourServiceBus.dll");
ps.AddCommand("Import-Module").AddParameter("Assembly", ass).Invoke();
var result = ps.AddCommand("Get-SBNamespace").Invoke();
```

Hope this could help.